# Prove the equation $\left(2x^2+1\right)\left(2y^2+1\right)=4z^2+1$ has no solution in the positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Prove the equation 
$$\left(2x^2+1\right)\left(2y^2+1\right)=4z^2+1$$
has no solution in the positive integers

#### My work:

1) I have the usually problem

$$\left(nx^2+1\right)\left(my^2+1\right)=(m+n)z^2+1$$

in the positive integers. Initially I use case $\gcd(m,n)=1$

2) Let $m=n=2$. It is this case. I need to prove that  $(x^2-y^2)^2+(x^2+y^2) $ is not perfect square for any $x,y$

Comment: Seems to be hard. I tried infinite descent, but I failed. Also considering the prime factors of $2x^2+1$,$2y^2+1$ and $4z^2+1$ led to nowhere. I am curious whether someone can solve this ...

Comment: If it's any help, it's easy to prove the impossibility of the special case $x = y$.

Comment: Another observation: by writing $z = xy + k$ the problem is transformed into $x^2 + y^2 = 4kxy + 2k^2$, which may be a bit friendlier (it's at least closer to being homogeneous in $x$ and $y$).

Comment: Could you clarify the relevance, in (2), of the expression $(x^2 - y^2)^2 + (x^2 + y^2)$, which equals $x^4 - 2x^2y^2 + y^4 + x^2 + y^2$?  With its 4th powers, it seems unrelated to your initial problem statement.

Comment: In the case of $(2)$ (equation in the title) it can be shown that $x,y,z$ must be divisible by $3$, hence there is no solution in positive integers when $$36m^2n^2+2m^2+2n^2$$ cannot be a positive perfect square. But this apparently does not help much.

Comment: Seems to be hard for me, too. Work mod 16 proves $x, y$ both even. But, using $2^k$, the largest power of 2 dividing both $x$ and $y$, what succeeds in disproving $k=0$ fails to rule out $k=1$.

Comment: Work in mod 3 proves x, y, z all divisible by 3, and work in mod 8 proves x, y, z all divisible by 2. Observe $gcd(x,y)=gcd(x,z)=gcd(y,z)=gcd(x,y,z)=k$. Divide by $k^2$. Problem turns into $2x^2y^2k^2+x^2+y^2=2z^2$ for x, y, z pairwise relatively prime. Note 6 divides k. In this new problem, it can be proven 2 does not divide x, y, or z in mod 8. Therefore, the gcd must have taken all 2's out of the prime factorization of the original x, y and z, meaning the original x, y, z have the same number of 2's in their prime factorization. Same goes for 3 in mod 3.

Comment: Found similar question: [Math Overflow Link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304892/2x212y21-4z21-has-no-positive-integer-solutions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says in the comments this is [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304892/2x212y21-4z21-has-no-positive-integer-solutions) on Math Overflow. The only solution is indeed the trivial one: $(0,0,0)$. This can be found in Theorem 6 in Kashihara: [Explicit complete solution in integers of a class of equations.](https://eudml.org/doc/155881)

Comment: My main reason for posting this answer was to remove it from the list of unanswered questions. This was answered quite a while back in the comments. I am a little curious about the delete vote... I would expect this answer to maintain no upvotes and no down votes because it's mostly just site maintenance but why the delete vote?

Comment: You have to ping the reviewer who voted to delete your answer in the [LQR](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1119806) so that he knows you're asking him.

Answer (score 1):

The question is concerned only with $x,y,z\ge 1$. $x=y$ does not give a solution (see comments). WLOG assume $x>y$. Look at the equation $\mod x$.

$1\cdot (2y^2+1)\equiv 4z^2+1\mod x$.

Let $z\equiv a\mod x$. Then $2y^2+1=4(nx+a)^2+1$.

Subtracting $1$ from each side and dividing by $2$ we get $y^2=2(nx+a)^2\Rightarrow 2=\frac{y^2}{(nx+a)^2}\ $ which would make $\sqrt{2}$ rational.
Hence there are no positive integers that satisfy the equation.

Comment: There's a mistake in your proof, you can't conclude that  $2y^2+1=4(nx+a)^2+1$

Comment: I think  from your argument you can conclude that $2y^2+1=mx+4(nx+a)^2+1$ because you started by saying consider it $\mod x \dots$ Anyway. I don't think this one will have an easily contained answer given that the Kashihara paper I reference takes several pages to do this.